# Using Moment.js or Moment Time Zones, match up Standard time and Daylight Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I've been trying to find a library or JavaScript solution for matching up times from different parts of the year in the United States.

The issue is that a news agency publishes articles and updates them as well.
The article can be published in June and then updated for whatever reason in December.

They are sticking with the preference that they need EST and EDT at the end of their times but don't like it when the cases don't match.

So far I've tried js and moment time zones (output below as well):

```
var a = moment("2015-06-04T15:09:06Z");
var b = moment("2015-12-03T16:09:07Z");

a.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a z');
// "Thursday, June 4th 2015, 11:09 am EDT"
b.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a z');
// "Thursday, December 3rd 2015, 11:09 am EST”
```

You can see the outputs have non matching ends (EDT and EST). Since it's ST right now, they want both to say the correct time in EST or CST etc. And when it is daylight savings time, they want it to say the correct time in EDT, CDT, PDT, etc.

I've also tried writing the solution in JS as well but long story short, I'd have to use a renderDate function to place the date that someone created a long time ago and that uses document.write that of course wipes the page. I'm going to try to avoid that.

The time is already given to me in moment.js format though, ie 2015-06-04T15:09:06Z so I thought I might find a way to do it through the new time zone addon.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Why would they have the same abbreviation if they are for different times of the year?  I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: If it's just that they don't like it, well too bad for them. That's how time zones work.

Comment: That's how I feel but the upper management doesn't feel that way. What the client wants is if it's standard time now the time that is not is converted to match. It doesn't seem worth the trouble. I say it was daylight savings so that's the way it should be reported. I could not sway any minds so therefore I have to find an answer.

Comment: It's not about how one feels.  It's about what is correct and what is not.  I might feel like I want 1+2 to equal 4, but that doesn't make it so.  It sounds like it's your job to educate "upper management" about how time zones actually work.  May I suggest: http://codeofmatt.com/2014/04/27/time-zone-abbreviations/ and also http://codeofmatt.com/2015/02/07/what-is-a-time-zone/

Comment: @MattJohnson I enjoyed the article but I don't know how it can help me convince ppl that the client is ludicrous for wanting to change the name of what that time actually is. It's like trying to say to Bart, your name is Fred now which is what I've tried to argue already. Ah this crazy world.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what else to suggest.  You could grab the time zone abbreviation of a *different* time and show that instead, or just use the same abbreviations on both manually, but you're not going to get the library to lie about it for you.  If you want to reach me privately, I'd be happy to discuss options for providing assistance more directly.

Comment: That's ok, I appreciate the replies. I have written code that can take the time and change the middle letter to match what is the current offset and then I'm hoping moment.js can just add or subtract an hour from the time which is what i need to dig more on. And then I can re-inject the time into the div that currently holds the "correct" times. I just need to get moment.tz into our system. As I stated above, I already had written a solution in JS but didn't want to use their document write function to post the new date. I just wish there was an easier way. Many thanks!

Comment: Changing the middle letter won't work worldwide.  Consider London, whose abbreviations are GMT/BST, and France, whose abbreviations are CET/CEST (and countless others).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me refine a bit more and test a few more cases. I used moment's timezone guessing feature and this helps take care of that part along with code that tests for offsets, I seem to have a solution for the United States in order to match up the time stamps. You're right though, I'm stopping at the rest of the world. I think ppl are going to live with that. I'll place it here below, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer:

```
function dst() {
if (wng_pageInfo.containerType === "S") { 

    var postedTime;
    var updatedTime;

    Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
        var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
        var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
        return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
    }

    Date.prototype.dst = function() {
        return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
    }

    var today = new Date();
    if (today.dst()) { 
        console.log("Daylight savings time!"); 

        postedTime = moment($('time:first').attr('datetime'));
        postedTimeFormat = postedTime.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a z');
        if (postedTimeFormat.indexOf('ST') !== -1) {
            postedTime = postedTime.tz(moment.tz.guess()).add(1, 'hour').format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a z');
            postedTime = postedTime.replace('ST','DT');
        } else {
            $('time:first').text(postedTimeFormat);
        };

        updatedTime = moment($('time:last').attr('datetime'));
        updatedTimeFormat = updatedTime.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a z');
        if (updatedTimeFormat.indexOf('ST') !== -1) {
            updatedTime = updatedTime.tz(moment.tz.guess()).add(1, 'hour').format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a z');
            updatedTime = updatedTime.replace('ST','DT');
            $('time:last').text(updatedTime);
        } else {
            $('time:last').text(updatedTimeFormat);
        };

    } else { 

        console.log("not Daylight savings time"); 

        postedTime = moment($('time:first').attr('datetime'));
        postedTimeFormat = postedTime.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a z');
        if (postedTimeFormat.indexOf('DT') !== -1) {
            postedTime = postedTime.tz(moment.tz.guess()).subtract(1, 'hour').format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a z');
            postedTime = postedTime.replace('DT','ST');
            $('time:first').text(postedTime);
        } else {
            $('time:first').text(postedTimeFormat);
        }

        updatedTime = moment($('time:last').attr('datetime'));
        updatedTimeFormat = updatedTime.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a z');
        if (updatedTimeFormat.indexOf('DT') !== -1) {
            updatedTime = updatedTime.tz(moment.tz.guess()).subtract(1, 'hour').format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a z');
            updatedTime = updatedTime.replace('DT','ST');
            $('time:last').text(updatedTime);
        } else {
            $('time:last').text(updatedTimeFormat);
        };
    };
};
}
```

This was quite a mind bender for me. I think it covers all scenarios though.